# 500 Error on Heroku hosted PHP Website, from .htaccess Config file

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, heroku

I'm working on an API with PHP Language, and I'm confused regarding why it works fine offline but not online on Heroku. Within the root directory, there is a ".htaccess" file.

Problem:
Offline, it works just fine when tested with the postman, but when tested online, it throws back 500 errors, nothing changed, just the run environment.

Codes:

```
Options -Indexes

 <Files .htaccess>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
 </Files>

 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 FileETag None
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Purpose of the .htaccess code above is, `Option` line protects directories, the `<Files>` line protects my htaccess file, the `AddDefaultCharset` line cleans URL for user profile, from the `RewriteEngine on` line, it is intended to remove .php from the file, and also allow multiple parameters on PHP like, `index/param1/param2/...` which would serve as endpoints.

And it works just fine offline, and online it doesn't except 500 error as seen in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

After checking the Heroku Log here is what I found.

[image]

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: The tail result from the log @Chris

2022-02-28T16:44:26.172343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/v1/index/user/fetch/all" host=olevelguru.herokuapp.com request_id=353efe3f-ba1c-4743-97a2-2880b4d3ec90 fwd="102.90.2.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=279 protocol=https

Found nothing helpful here

Comment: @PreciousTom, that's just one line. Show _all of it_, please. And do so by editing your question, not by commenting.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, but [please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). That log output should be shared as a code block. In any case, you're right, there isn't much information there. You'll need to add some log statements to whatever code handles `/v1/index/user/fetch/all`.